# Where does the imaginary unit dissapear in the Fourier transform of $f(t)= \exp(iat)$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

1. So I make the Fourier transform of$ f(t)= e^{iat} $on $[- \pi, \pi]$ for some real $a$ and i get:

$$a_n=\frac{2a \sin(a \pi)(-1)^n}{\pi(a^2-n^2)}$$
$$b_n=\frac{2i(n\sin(a \pi) (-1)^n)}{\pi(a^2 - n^2)}$$

But now if i want to evaluate the sum at $t=\pi$, at the part of the series with $b_n \sin (nx)$ i get 0 and therefore there is no imaginary part in the whole series. Why is this the case?

2. $f \in C^{\infty}$ but the series don't seen to be [normally convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) (which should be the case if $f$ was a real function). Is that because we are now working with complex numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re 2: It is not true that $f \in C^\infty$ (for general values of $a$). Note that we are looking at the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the given $f$. For most values of $a$, $f(\pi) \neq f(-\pi)$ which implies that the periodic extension of $f$ is **not** continuous at odd multiples of $\pi$.

However, $f$ is smooth enough to guarantee that the Fourier series of $f$ evaluated at $t=\pi$ converges the average of $\lim_{t\to \pi^-} f(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to \pi^+} f(t)$ i.e. to
$$
\frac{e^{ia\pi} + e^{-ia\pi}}{2} = \cos a\pi
$$
which is real.

Comment: Thank you! I should have checked the continuity haha :)